# Why an extra layer(HAL) between library and kernel layer?

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, kernel, hal

For Linux OS running on x86 hardware, to invoke `TCP_listen()` that is part of TCP/IP driver(for x86) in kernel, user space client application calls `listen()` interface which is part of user space `glibc` library[GNU distri.].

`listen()` in turn calls `sys_Listen()` before entering into kernel mode via `INT 0x80` software interrupt for invoking kernel mode `TCP_listen()` system call.

So,  `glibc` library layer directly provides a vendor neutral interface i.e., `listen()` to run vendor(x86) specific TCP/IP driver system call `TCP_listen()`, which is part of Linux kernel.

## [image]

My question:

In Android world, I would like to understand the purpose of extra layer(HAL) in between libraries(Bionic Libc) and Linux kernel.

Note: Am new to Android world, May be, `listen()` would not be the right example to use in android stack.

Note: I know many threads answering similar query on SO.

Comment: One business reason could be, Linux kernel drivers hold GPL license. So, source code need to get shipped along, which vendors like Samsung/NOKIA would not be willing to. Any technical reason?

Comment: Different GPS drivers, for example, might provide a different interface to userspace. (Different IOCTLs, etc.) So this HAL serves to abstract that so it can be used uniformly by the Android code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I guess, a Vendor modifies kernel layer and HAL layer to introduce his new driver. Does Vendor also get permission to modify bionic Libc as part of introducing new driver at HAL/kernel layer? Does that make sense technically as a user of bionic Libc?

Comment: Modifying `libc` to add a new driver? Sounds horrible... They have nothing to do with each other

Answer (score 0):

***(Disclaimer: I'm a noob with respect to this question. I'm just trying to naively provide pointers to other information sources.)***

I think the Android Camera interface - viewing it from both above and below the Camera HAL, will help illuminate the role played by the HAL layer.

Simply put, HAL exists to give a unified interface (to the framework or application) access to vendor-specific implementations.

And by "vendor-specific", I don't mean they conform to any open specification. In fact, they might not.

The cameras in mobile devices are not USB cameras. They are [CSI-MIPI interface cameras](http://mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface). But still, it wouldn't stop a vendor from trying to support USB cameras from Android.

The Android Java programming interface `android.hardware.camera2` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)) is the API used by the framework and application.

The Camera HAL v3 ([link](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3.html)) talks to the vendor-specific stuff.

In that diagram, under the space labeled "Linux Kernel", it does not necessarily imply that camera module vendors share any source code with outside. It might as well be binary blobs (compiled code) that are loaded into and execute in the kernel space.